# Retrieving Data from SQL Using pyodbc through Set Comprehension gives unhashable type: 'pyodbc.Row'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I need to run SELECT statements for a list of files in a set. I am using the following code snippet:

```
def flist_in_psumsdb(config, fnames_set_in_psumsdictlist):
    constring = config['db_string## Heading ##']['db_string']
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(constring)
    cnxnset = {  row for row in  {(cnxn.execute(f"""SELECT LOG FROM {config['db_string']['bd_psums_meta_table_str']} where LOG = '{log}'  """)).fetchone() for log in fnames_set_in_psumsdictlist} }
    cnxn.close()
```

However when I run this I get error:

```
  File "c:\Users\sys_nsgprobeingestio\Documents\dozie\odfs\etesthad4.py", line 458, in <setcomp>
    cnxnset = {  row for row in       {(cnxn.execute(f"""SELECT LOG FROM {config['db_string']['bd_psums_meta_table_str']} where LOG = '{log}'  """)).fetchone() for log in fnames_set_in_psumsdictlist} }
TypeError: unhashable type: 'pyodbc.Row'
```

The idea is to iterate through cnxset and return the list of log files from the rows of pyodbc like this:

```
filelist = {row.LOG for row in cnxnset}
```

where LOG is the column of course from the sql select statement

Comment: That doesn't work here because I am supposed to be getting a particular list of logs from my script. I don't need distinct logs from the DB. The DB has 50k logs in it. I only need a set of those logs as specified from my script @snakecharmerb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an iterable of log names, they could be retrieved using an `IN` query.

First, we need to build the values substitution clause:

```py
names = fnames_set_in_psumsdictlist

subs = ', '.join(['?' for name in names])
```

Now we can build the complete query and execute it.

```py
q = f"""SELECT LOG 
FROM {config['db_string']['bd_psums_meta_table_str']} 
WHERE LOG IN ({subs}); """

cursor.execute(q, names)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Note that different database drivers have different substitution parameters - pyodbc uses `'?'` some others use `'%s'`.  Using substitution parameters rather than string interpolation ensures that values are correctly quoted in the query.

Comment: Somebody just told me getting queries from string concatenations are a terrible unsecure way of doing stuff like this. Mind you I am doing this for my internship at a Tech company. My mentor's answer is the same as yours in that he uses string concat as well. Except he didn't do the %s thing you did. Should I be concerned?

Comment: Why do you include the list  names in the execute statemetn? @snakecharmerb

Comment: There are 3 things going on here: 1. Using string interpolation to bind values to the query (in the where clause) - this is bad because values may be incorrectly quoted '2020-08-05' could be treated as an arithmetical expression, or worse, a malicious user could [inject a string of SQL to change the effect of the query](https://xkcd.com/327/). 2. Building the param list `(?, ?, ...)` using `string.join` - this ok, this is just a placeholder; 3. Using string interpolation for the table name: ideally we would quote this using the db's preferred quote character (varies by db).  GL with internship